# Vim/R @ Character in CSV

Tags: r, vim

I tried to read a csv file into R, but it's getting hung up. After inspecting the file in VIM at the problem spot, I saw that there are several lines of at symbols (@) in the middle of one of my entries like

```
,somedata  
@  
@  
@  
@  
continued data,
```

I don't know much about the at symbols in VIM, but I'm guessing these aren't actually at symbols but some kind of formatting character. How can I get rid of them? There are plenty of articles about how to suppress viewing them in VIM, but I am fairly certain I must remove them in order to read in my csv successfully.

Comment: Vim uses this for lines that are too long to display, given the size of the terminal. Those characters are not in the file, so there is no need to worry about them. But your file may be corrupted: for instance, some or all newline characters may be missing.

Comment: Is it possible that those are `^@` characters? This is a replacement char for zeros ... a sign that your file might have been corrupted.

Comment: I found out the @'s weren't the actual problem. It was a double quotation mark. Thanks for trying everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You could delete lines starting with @ in vim using the following statement:

```
:g/@/d
```

Or you could read the `*.csv` to R and @ as a comment char

```
read.csv("file.csv", comment.char="@")
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless jmsigner is being cynical, his answer might actually destroy or at least alter the source file because the @ characters are used by Vim to tell that a line longer than the terminal width got broken to be able to be displayed in its entirety.

In Vim go to command mode and type (without quotes) ":set nowrap". This will disable "line wrapping" so you need to scroll (way) to the right to be able to see some of the lines entirely. It DOES give you, however, a clean view of how the source file exactly looks like.